# How to set session expiry for a html page in MVC using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have  a html page in mvc and i also have a buttton click function in it. How can I redirect to login page if the pge is kept idle for 30 minutes?
I have tried the following code..

```
setTimeout(function () { '@Url.Action("LogOn", "Account")'; }, 1800000);
```

But it is not working properly. Thanks in advance

Comment: for your problem you shouldn't use js. How you authenticate your users? Show your server side code please.

Comment: Session expiration logic better to be handled on server side (i.e. sliding expiration). You can set timer on view page to show expired session alert instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this only to redirect the user to the login page so that he is aware of the expired session. The timeout must be set on server side.

Try

```
setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "/Account/LogOn/" }, 1800000);
```

But you should also have this in your web.config

```
 <system.web>    
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="30"/>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear it should  be server side

you can set a timer by javascript and by ajax hit server method that take you to login and reset the session but its not a best practice